# Recoverable fatal error: Object of class connect could not be converted to string

Tags: php

I've used class to connect to database as a model. When when I called it in controller show below error

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class connect could not be converted to string in
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\awebarts\admin\model\connect.php on line 24 include '../model/connect.php';

```
<?php 

include '../model/connect.php';

$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "awebarts";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
 
$connect = new connect($host,$dbname,$user,$pass);

class connect {
    private $host ;
    private $dbname ;
    private $user ;
    private $pass ;
    public $con ;

    function __construct($host,$dbname,$user,$pass){  
        
        $this->$host = $host;
        $this->$dbname = $dbname;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;

        $this->database();
    }

    private function database(){

        try{
            $this->con = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->$host; dbname=$this->dbname", $this->user, $this->pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
            $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        }catch(PDOException $e){

            echo 'cannot connect to database' . $e->getmessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your problem but maybe: `$this->$host = $host;` should this be `$this->host = $host`
`$this->$dbname = $dbname;` should this be `$this->dbname= $dbname` Then you have The same below in the database method

Comment: Instead of SET NAMES utf8, you should specify the charset in DSN, and I recommend to use utf8mb4 instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your DSN string is wrong. You can't have spaces and property interpolation in the string.

```
new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->dbname.";charset=utf8mb4", $this->user, $this->pass);
```

Also see Antony's comment about a typo.

Answer (score 0):

change `$this->$dbname` to `$this->dbnamme` and `$this->$host` to `$this->host` and make change in code

```
$this->con = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host; dbname=$this->dbname", $this->user, $this->pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
```